# How does graphql minimize round trips when compared to REST?

Tags: graphql

I am not able to get how GraphQL can minimize no of calls to get data from multiple endpoints.
For example, we have 2 endpoints :

1. one that gives information of post including post author id by post id

socialmedia.com/posts/:postid

2. another that gives information of post author by user id

socialmedia.com/authors/:authorid

My use case is i first get author id from post details and then author details based on author id.
If i were a rest client, i would make 2 calls 2 these endpoints.

How can this be minimized when using graphql?

Comment: By having one endpoint, conventionally `/graphql`, to which you can make a single request that returns post _and_ author data according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you set up your GraphQL schema. But let's assume you have two types in your schema:

```
type Author {
 id: ID!
 name: String
 posts: [Post!]
}

type Post {
  id: ID!
  body: String
  author: Author!
}
```

So an Author has many Posts, and a Post has a single Author. For the sake of example, let's also assume you have a top-level query that let's you retrieve all the Posts:

```
query Query {
 allPosts: [Post!]
}
```

Now, suppose you want to load all posts along with the Author name. Your query might look like this:

```
query AllPostsWithAuthors {
  allPosts {
    id
    body
    author {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

The server should resolve that query and provide exactly the information you requested, all in a single round trip.
But again - it depends on how you set up your schema. GraphQL itself is just a specification, and it's a pretty relaxed one at that. I see a lot of people (myself included) struggle with the "paradigm shift" to think in terms of Graphs rather than in terms of resources & endpoints, and they end up designing APIs with a RESTish mentality, wrapped up in GraphQL, and the result is not good. I highly recommend this article: https://graphqlme.com/2017/11/11/build-better-graphql-apis-thinking-in-graphs/

Comment: Thanks. I should have phrased my question better.  My understanding is The graphQL server will have to internally make 2 calls to the endpoints before returning the result to the caller. Am i right?

Comment: Oh, so you're using the GraphQL as a proxy to a REST API? If that's the case, then yes - the GraphQL server would have to absorb that hit. But your client only has to make the single call to the GraphQL server, so it's still a win. And you could implement your GraphQL server with some intelligent caching. For example, if you already have the `Author` in the cache, then you can avoid making the trip to the `socialmedia.com/authors/:authorid` endpoint.